# Zelda: the Triforce and the Sierpinski triangle

Tags: legend-of-zelda-series, the-legend-of-zelda

The [Triforce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triforce) artifact found in many Legend of Zelda games bears a great deal of resemblance to the fractal known as the The [Sierpinski triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle#History) (Triforce on top, Sierpinski triangle below):

[image: Triforce] [image: Sierpinski triangle below]

They are each a single equilateral triangle (typically) composed of three equilateral triangles joined at the corners.  The difference is that the Sierpinski triangle repeats this pattern repeats in each progressively smaller triangle, while the triforce.  The triforce is basically the second iteration of the Sierpinski triangle:

[image: Sierpinski triangle iterations]

My question is whether there is any reason to think that the triforce was intentionally based on the Sierpinski triangle, or whether it was a coincidence.  I can imagine scenarios either way, so I was wondering if there is any statements or evidence (such as file names, concept art, off-the-cuff comments, etc.) one way or the other.

Comment: The very first Zelda game came out on the NES, which had very limited processing power and storage space. I suspect the shape was chosen because it was easy to draw with the limited hardware that was available, and has remained the same shape for consistency's sake.

Comment: That being said, there's not really any way of knowing the answer for sure unless a developer specifically answers...  which means this question is off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 4):

Speculation exists that it originates from Japanese clans, in particular, the Hojo clan.

Wikipedia image for [Hojo clan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_H%C5%8Dj%C5%8D_clan) crest:

[image]

[This site](https://zeldauniverse.net/2010/11/15/of-samurais-and-dragons-origins-of-the-triforce-part-1/) covers this theory. Image below of related crests, from the same site.

[image]